# highcharts Export XLS files on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, highcharts

I am using below plugin to export High charts in Excel format :

[enter link description here](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data)

it works well but when I try to export on client side mode be adding below JS to page

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```

all additional options to export file disappear ( XLS , Data table , ..) and only default options still remaining.

is there a solution for this case or is there another plug in available to do the both jobs ?

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of the scripts. Offline exporting module should be loaded after exporting module but before export-csv module.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cqjvD/1317/

Answer (score 0):

I found another libraray which combines the 2 features ( Offline exporting + XLS exporting) :

[HIGHCHARTS-EXPORT-CLIENTSIDE](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/37/highcharts-export-clientside)